# Firefox webdriver stops responding at the specific page

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My trouble is that firefox webdriver stops responding at the specific web-page. The code is so simple:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://ok.ru')

lgn = 'tester919191'
pswd = 'tester919191!!@#@'

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#field_email').send_keys(lgn)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#field_password').send_keys(pswd)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input.button-pro').click()

for i in xrange(100):
    print i, browser.current_url
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am trying here to sign in the Russian social network. So after about 10 seconds the browser stops responding and the interpreter hangs at the line `browser.current_url`. I have tried to use many different firefox versions and I have got the same result nonetheless. Selenium version I have tried to use is 2.45.0 or 2.44.0. My assumption is that there is some JS-code crashing the webdriver on this page. By the way my code works perfectly at the main page (with no signing in).

**UPDATE**

Running the code above I have got the following result:

```
0 http://ok.ru/
1 http://ok.ru/
2 http://ok.ru/
3 http://ok.ru/
4 http://ok.ru/
5 http://ok.ru/
6 http://ok.ru/
7 http://ok.ru/
8 http://ok.ru/
9

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/sele.py", line 15, in <module>
    print i, browser.current_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 428, in current_url
    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 380, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Exception raised after about 5 minutes of interpreter hanging.

Comment: So, depending on a selenium server version and firefoxdriver version AND firefox version it will not work completely untill you will not get the latest ones. What is your FF version? The latest one is perfectly working with latest selenium server and firefoxdriver.

Comment: I use Firefox 35.0 and python-selenium 2.45.0. So I do not use selenium server at all, I run local browser using python-selenium integrated webdriver. Firefox v35.0 is the latest supported version (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/py/CHANGES).

Comment: This is an open issue in selenium.http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6955